# Where is Castle's AbstractFacility class?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, castle-activerecord

I am trying to compile Castle.Facilities.ActiveRecordIntegration with the trunk version of Castle.Core.

ARIntegration uses 'AbstractFacility', which sits in the Castle.MicroKernel DLL.

The DLL is now nowhere to be found. Where is ARIntegration/MicroKernel? How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Castle.MicroKernel.dll was recently merged into Castle.Windsor.dll, that's where you'll find the class.

Why don't you use ARFacility with released version of Windsor and AR? Do you need any of the new features added after the release?

Generally using released versions is advised wherever possible.

Comment: Yeap, I found that reverting to using the release version is the way to go here.